# how do I set setOnPageChangeListener?

Tags: android, fragment

I create and set up my Fragment inside my FragmentActivity like this:

```
public class PosFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
        ...
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()
                , numOfPositionsForClass);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        ...
    }
...
}
```

How do I add the `setOnPageChangeListener` so when the Tab/Fragment/Page is scrolled, it calls a method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the listener on the ViewPager object.

This is done through the [ViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOnPageChangeListener%28android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener%29) method.

You can either implement your own [ViewPager.OnPageChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html)

or

subclass the provided [ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener.html)

```
Example:
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener( new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() );
```

Comment: Where do I put my methods (onPageScrolled(), onPageSelected, etc)?

Comment: Check my edit, you either have to create a class that implements the OnPageChangedListener interface, or you can subclass SimpleOnPageChangedListener

Answer (score 7):

```
pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
     @Override
     public void onPageSelected(int position) 
     {     
     }
     @Override
     public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state)
     {
     }
     @Override
     public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels)
     {
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

setOnPageChangeListener is now deprecated so use this instead :

```
ViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```